# R - Creating a fuzzy correspondance analysis

Tags: r, analysis, fuzzy

I have ecological data of benthic invertebrate species traits. I would like to do a fuzzy correspondance analysis with ade4-package. I have trait sub-categories as columns and benthic sampling places as rows.

I have prepared and plotted a matrix of fuzzy variables with my "painotettu" dataframe using [prep.fuzzy.var](//pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/dudi.fca.html) from ade4-package.

```
library("ade4", lib.loc="~/Library/R/3.0/library")

w <- prep.fuzzy.var(
    painotettu, 
    c(5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3,    
      5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 3)
)

scatter(dudi.fpca(w, scann = FALSE, nf = 3), csub = 2, type = 0, clab.moda = 2)
```

The result:

[image]

The result is very unclear and to sort it out, I have been trying to:

1. Separate the places into one picture and traits into another
2. Delete the text boxes so that the names could be seen more easily.
3. I'm also searching for some function that would compute a matrix that would give numerical values of what the arrows represent.

I'm trying to sort the data to look more like this:

[image]

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.